# Jquery fails to capture <form> submit event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, post

I have a form with a submit button named Apply,

#### Visual

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
       <h3><a href="#">Theme color and layout</a></h3>
       <div>
       <!-- Colour picker code -->
        <form id="applyColor">
           <input class='simple_color' value='#cc3333'/>     
           <input type='submit' value='Apply'/>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

#### Javascript

```
//Colour picker
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.simple_color').simpleColor();

    $("#applyColor").submit(function() {
        alert($('input.simple_color')[0].value);
    });
});
```

### Problem :

Now, Whenever I click on submit button it doesn't execute my alert statement. I have tried to use simple alert statement like `alert('Hello World!');` but it did not work as well.

I am not sure whats wrong, am I doing something wrong?

---

#### Linked Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

#### Sources I used to create a color picker and tutorial regarding post via ajax,

- [Color picker](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2007/12/18/jquery-simplecolor-color-picker/)
- [How to post form via jquery ajax](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyXeOX-uYMc)

Comment: Do you have the `$.simpleColor()` plugin referenced?

Comment: I see it working in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/QL7n5/1/

Comment: @JonathanSampson, SimplePlugin part works perfectly

Comment: Check the fiddle everything seems to be working, is this specific to any browser ?

Comment: @Craftero Check the working demo in my answer to see if it also breaks for you.

Comment: @mprabhat, Yeah correct it works on jsbin and jsfiddle but not on my machine...I have properly referenced to simpleColor lib as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was only able to reproduce your problem when I didn't have the color picker properly referenced. When I did reference it, the solution worked as expected:

```
$(".simple_color").simpleColor();

$("#applyColor").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( 'Submitted' );
});
```

Working: http://jsbin.com/ejovir/2/edit
Not Working (plugin not referenced): http://jsbin.com/ejovir/3/edit

Check your console for a message similar to the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'simpleColor'

Comment: Yeah thats the only issue I think

Comment: I have correct reference to simpleColor and I not receiving the error you have mentioned. However, I can see same code works in jsfiddle and jsbin but not on my computer. I am using firefox to test.

Comment: @Craftero If you copy/paste my code from above, does that fix the problem?

Comment: Nope, just tried that...Very strange...I will try creating to create a new file and then test it.

Comment: @Craftero Your problem is not in the code you provided here then. If you can put the page online, that would help.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, yup you are right I had a big form encapsulating this applyColor form and thats why I didnt work...Now let me go and catch the person who did this bizzare thing :) Thanks btw